# Angular 2 include component html in a component inherited template

Tags: html, angular, templates

I have a component A with its html/ts file. When I inherit a second component B from A, this will take all properties and method on the first. If I want to use the component A html, I can reference the comp A html in the `templateUrl` property.

I have a problem. I want use the component A html, but I want extend it. So my idea is "include" the first component html to the second. It's possible in Angular2? Is there another way?

I don't want to create an instance of component A in the component B. I want only the html markup.

**EDIT:**

In this example there is my problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-projection-lzjwea

when I inherited the Hello2 ts, If I create an instance of hello component in hello2 html, it take its `name` property. I found three solutions:

1. Change all properties that need to be used in all inherit component to input and inject the
2. Duplicate html code
3. Find a way to reference the html of first component without creating an instance of it.

I think the best solution is the third. But I don't know a way to do it..

Comment: Will `ng-content` (Content Projection) work for you?

Comment: unfortunally no.. i created a example to show to you the problem in the main post

Answer (score 2):

`ng-content` could be used to project dynamic content in a component.

For example, consider the following

**hello.component.html**

```
<div id='border'>
    <h1>Base Component</h1>
    <p>ng-content could be used for projecting dynamic content within a component</p>
    <ng-content>
        <!-- Dynamic content goes here -->
    </ng-content>
</div>
```

So, now whatever that is in between

```
<hello>
    <!-- dynamic html here -->
</hello>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <h2>Child Component</h2>
    <button id="sample1"> Sample 1 </button>
    <button id="sample2"> Sample 2 </button>
  </div>
</hello>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-projection)

Hope this helps

Comment: i know ng-content, but can't resolve my problem. I created a example to show to you my problem. It is in the main problem.